# Creating a newline breaks entire page?

Tags: line-breaking, page-breaking, templates, cv, deedy-resume

I'm using LuaLaTeX and I tried using a template found at: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/deedy-resume-cv

However, when I try running it using Texmaker, the page splits into 2. Any idea how I can fix this?

[image]

Comment: Without a full example, I can only speculate that the two `minipage`s creating the left/right columns are just big enough to fit on the page. Introducing a line break via ``\\`` in the `\namesection` causes a reduction in the available space on the page, thereby letting the `minipage`s (unbreakable blocks) to spill over. You could attempt to issue `\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}` immediately after `\namesection`.

Comment: Thanks, your solution worked perfectly. Putting `\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}`  immediately after `\namesection` solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LaTeX template creates a two-columned look by constructing a "title block" and two `minipage`s making up the "two columnar blocks". Since `minipage`s form unbreakable blocks, they will spill over to/be placed on the next page if there isn't enough room on the current page.

The introduction of a line break does exactly that: it makes the `minipage`s not fit on the current page anymore, therefore issuing a break to the following page.

There are many ways to circumvent this behaviour:

1. Issue `\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}` somewhere on the first page which adds a single line to the page goal, allowing one additional line to be inserted at the bottom of the text block.
2. Use a smaller font somewhere.
3. Provide the `minipage`'s with a fixed height.
4. Resize the `minipage`s to a proportion of their height (using [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)'s `\resizebox{!}{.9\height}{...}` say).
5. Adjust the vertical spacing between the `\namesection` and the columnar block using `\vspace{-\baselineskip}` say (if there is enough whitespace to accommodate for this adjustment).
6. ...